# Failing to call a function from one PHP file to the other without getting errors

Tags: php, function, database-connection, function-calls

I am trying to call some data from a database to an app I'm making, however am struggling to with a small problem.

FILE: Dbconnect.php

```
<?php

connect();

function __destruct() {
    $this->close();
}

function connect() {

    require_once __DIR__ . '/Config.php';

    $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or     die(mysql_error());

    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());

    return $con;

}

function close() {

    mysql_close();

}
?>
```

FILE: Get_Subjects.php

```
<?php

require_once 'Dbconnect.php';

function getSubjects(){
    $db = new connect();
?>
```

When I try to call the connect(); function in Get_Subjects.php it comes up with this error:

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'connect' not found in G:\PleskVhosts\opuna.co.uk\httpdocs\subject_api\Get_Subjects.php on line 6

I don't know why this keeps happening.

Comment: `$db = new connect();` is the code to instantiate a new object from a class. To call a function you simply do `functionName();`, or if you want to get a returned value `$returnedValue = functionName();`

Comment: you have this part twice ` or die(mysql_error())`

Comment: and `mysql_*` is deprecated.

Comment: How would I change it to code which isn't deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

`connect()` is a function, not a class. So you just need to call it without the `new`

```
function getSubjects(){
    $db = connect();
?>
```